# Returning a render window from class

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm a bit stuck with how i return my render window from my class, not sure if i have the return type wrong or the syntax or both !

My main.cpp has:

```
Window Render(800, 600, "Test");
sf::RenderWindow window = Render.Init();
```

My class for this is:

```
        Window::Window(int x, int y, std::string title){
            ResoX = x;
            ResoY = y;
            Title = title;
        }

    sf::RenderWindow Window::Init(){
        return screen(sf::VideoMode(ResoX,ResoY,Title));
    }
```

The header for the class:

```
class Window
{
    private:
        int ResoX, ResoY;            
        std::string Title;
        sf::RenderWindow screen;
    public:
    Window(int, int, std::string);

    sf::RenderWindow Init();
};
```

My errors are:

`error C2665: 'sf::VideoMode::VideoMode' : none of the 3 overloads could convert all the argument types
could be 'sf::VideoMode::VideoMode(unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int)'
 while trying to match the argument list '(int, int, std::string)'`

`error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments`

Does any one know how i fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From SFML document(**http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/1.6/classsf_1_1VideoMode.php#a9478572db06121f70260e6b9dc21704e**)

sf::VideoMode constructor is declared as:

```
sf::VideoMode::VideoMode(unsigned int   ModeWidth,
                         unsigned int   ModeHeight,
                         unsigned int   ModeBpp = 32 
                         )
```

which means you can't pass 3rd parameter as string, you can call it:

```
return screen(sf::VideoMode(ResoX,ResoY));
```